# Post method in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/customer',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: { test: 'testvalue' }
};

$http(req).then(function(){
    console.log("f1")
},function(){
    console.log("f2")
});
```

The code above posts this:

> { '{"test":"testvalue"}': '' }

When I need something like this:

> {"test":"testvalue"}

Does any one know the solution to this problem?

Comment: I would try something like var test = "testvalue"; and then data: test

Answer (score 1):

Use `$http.post` method:

```
$http.post('/customer', { test: 'testvalue' }, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(){
    console.log("f1")
},function(){
    console.log("f2")
});
```

Comment: This gives the same wrong output { '{"test":"testvalue"}': '' }